# Compare Products link does not work

Tags: products, compare

My product comparison link doesn't work. This is in Magento 1.9.

[My issues are almost identical to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593345/compare-products-sidebar-item-doesnt-show-products), with the exception that clearing the index did not work. Is there anything else I can try?

Here are the issues:

When I click "Add to Compare" on a product, a message stating that "such-and-such product successfully added to compare list" appears.

However the compare products sidebar shows "You have no items to compare."

I can tell the table `catalog_compare_item` is being populated with the correct visitor ID and product ID, but if I do a `print_r($this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getItemCount())` in template/catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml, "0" is returned.

Why won't the sidebar show the products to compare?

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, it looks like your Magento DB does not have report_compared_product_index table.

Import the following SQL to create this table structure in your DB.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `report_compared_product_index` (
`index_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Index Id',
  `visitor_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Visitor Id',
  `customer_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Customer Id',
  `product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Product Id',
  `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Store Id',
  `added_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Added At'
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Reports Compared Product Index Table' AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

ALTER TABLE `report_compared_product_index`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`index_id`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_REPORT_COMPARED_PRODUCT_INDEX_VISITOR_ID_PRODUCT_ID` (`visitor_id`,`product_id`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_REPORT_COMPARED_PRODUCT_INDEX_CUSTOMER_ID_PRODUCT_ID` (`customer_id`,`product_id`), ADD KEY `IDX_REPORT_COMPARED_PRODUCT_INDEX_STORE_ID` (`store_id`), ADD KEY `IDX_REPORT_COMPARED_PRODUCT_INDEX_ADDED_AT` (`added_at`), ADD KEY `IDX_REPORT_COMPARED_PRODUCT_INDEX_PRODUCT_ID` (`product_id`);
```

**I hope this will help you.**